# не происходят изменения при использовании .append внутри функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть функция

```
function typeCustomArray(aMin = NaN, aMax = NaN) {
  var text = "";
  $(".number_table").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (isNaN(aMin)&&isNaN(aMax)) {
      text += "<a>" + i + "</a>";
    } else {
      text += "<a>" + getRandomInt(aMin, aMax) + "</a>";
    }
  }
  $(".number_table").append(text);
}
```

И если я бегу дебагом, то все хорошо, и `number_table` очищается, и потом заполняется, но как только я выхожу из функции, изменения не применяются, то есть, то что было удалено `.empty()` возвращается, а то что было добавленно `.append()` не появляется.

Как можно это пофиксить?

Html:

```
<ul class="number_table">
    <a>TAD</a>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js">TypeCustomArray()</script>
</ul>
```

Функция `getRandomInt`:

```
function getRandomInt(aMin, aMax) {
   min = Math.ceil(aMin);
   max = Math.floor(aMax);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Пример html разметки надо тоже приводить, раз вы к ней что-то применяете........... к тому же когда в js стало возможным писать так параметры в функцию `function typeCustomArray(aMin = NaN, aMax = NaN)` ?  .....  и кто такой `getRandomInt` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, es6 + babel + дефолтные параметры

Comment: Как вызываете функцию, где вызываете функцию + html, пожалуйста

Comment: @ThisMan не вижу тут упоминания о babel ...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну как бы дефолтные параметры: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters
@ThisMan
Добавил код `getRandomInt` и html разметку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все работает, функция затирает все что есть внутри списка и выводит циклом инфу http://jsbin.com/hivovigora/1/edit?html,js,output

Старайтесь загружать jquery как можно выше в коде страницы, а не внутри списка ul. Возможно у вас в странице подключена jquery и не один раз.

И кстати у вас не прописан третий вариант `isNaN(aMin)||isNaN(aMax)`, когда функция вызывается с одним параметром.

```js
function getRandomInt(aMin, aMax) {
   min = Math.ceil(aMin);
   max = Math.floor(aMax);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function typeCustomArray(aMin = NaN, aMax = NaN) {
  var text = "";
  $(".number_table").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (isNaN(aMin)&&isNaN(aMax)) {
      text += "<a>" + i + "</a>";
    } else {
      text += "<a>" + getRandomInt(aMin, aMax) + "</a>";
    }
  }
  $(".number_table").append(text);
}

typeCustomArray();
typeCustomArray(0,100);
```

```css
a {
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<ul class="number_table">
    <a>TAD</a>
</ul>
```